# Grouping list of similar urls in python

Tags: python, url, optimization

I have a large sets of urls. Some are similar to each other i.e. they represent the similar set of pages.
For eg.

```
    http://example.com/product/1/
    http://example.com/product/2/
    http://example.com/product/40/
    http://example.com/product/33/
```

are similar. Similarly

```
    http://example.com/showitem/apple/
    http://example.com/showitem/banana/
    http://example.com/showitem/grapes/
```

are also similar. So i need to represent them as `http://example.com/product/(Integers)/`
where `(Integers) = 1,2,40,33` and  `http://example.com/showitem/(strings)/` where `strings = apple,banana,grapes` ... and so on.

Is there any inbuilt function or library in python to do find these similar urls from large set of mixed urls? How can this be done more efficiently? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need to do with them?

Comment: i need to detect list of these type of urls and group them from a set of different urls.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string to store the first part of the URL and just handle IDs, example:

```
In [1]: PRODUCT_URL='http://example.com/product/%(id)s/'

In [2]: _ids = '1 2 40 33'.split() # split string into list of IDs

In [3]: for id in _ids:
   ...:     print PRODUCT_URL % {'id':id}
   ...:     
http://example.com/product/1/
http://example.com/product/2/
http://example.com/product/40/
http://example.com/product/33/
```

The statement `print PRODUCT_URL % {'id':id}` uses Python [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to format the product URL depending on the variable `id` passed.

**UPDATE:**

I see you've changed your question. The solution for your problem is quite domain-specific and depends on your data set. There are several approaches, some more manual than others. One such approach would be to get the top-level URLs i.e. to retrieve the domain name:

```
In [7]: _url = 'http://example.com/product/33/' # url we're testing with

In [8]: ('/').join(_url.split('/')[:3]) # get domain
Out[8]: 'http://example.com'

In [9]: ('/').join(_url.split('/')[:4]) # get domain + first URL sub-part
Out[9]: 'http://example.com/product'
```

`[:3]` and `[:4]` above are just slicing the list resulting from `split('/')`

You can set the result as a key on a `dict` for which you keep a count of each time you encounter the URL part. And move on from there. Again the solution depends on your data. If it gets more complex than above then I suggest you look into regex as the other answers suggest.

Comment: This solution assumes that we already know the similar urls. But this is not the case. I have long list of urls which needs to detect similar urls automatically

Comment: @user2789099 updated my answer in response to your updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to handle that cases. You can go to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to see how is this handle.

Also you can see how Django implement this on its [routings system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what specifically you are looking for. It sounds to me that you are looking for something to match URLs. If this is indeed what you want then I suggest you use something that is built using regular expressions. One example can be found [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

I also suggest you take a look at [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and its [routing system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

Answer (score 0):

Not in Python, but I've created a Ruby Library (and an accompanying app) --

https://rubygems.org/gems/LinkGrouper

It works on all links (doesn't need to know any pattern).

Comment: Hi, are you actively maintaining this? The gem install command is not working. Is it possible to share the algorithm you used?